# URL routing in codeigniter must include '?' to work

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

So I installed CI with the default config and typed up the [sample codes] https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html.

I tried accessing the page via localhost/codeigniter/index.php/pages/view and apache gave me the 'not found - the URL you requested cant be found' error.

But if I type localhost/codeigniter/**index.php?**/pages/view, it works!

I tried changing the base url in application/config/config.php to blank, 'http://localhost/', and 'http://localhost/codeigniter/' but still no effects.

I've googled and looked the userguide and still found no solution.

Where do I have to look, what am I missing?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: You shouldn't need the ?, for it to work, no. As you have codeigniter running out of a subfolder, you'll probably want to keep your base_url set to `http://localhost/codeigniter/`

Comment: Could you post your `.htaccess` file, you may need to make an adjustment to account for the `/codeigniter/` subfolder your using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) is turned off in Apache. Try checking your Apache config for that directive, or perhaps manually set it to `On`.

Comment: Thank you! I added "AcceptPathInfo On" to my ubuntu's apache2.conf, restart, and it works rightaway